# What is the correct way to overlay an ActivityIndicator on BlackBerry 10?

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, qtquick2, blackberry-cascades

In my BB10 application I wish to overlay an `ActivityIndicator` in the centre of the current screen to indicate when something (e.g. "loading") is happening.

My current solution is to embed such an indicator in the centre of a custom transparent dialog, as follows:

```
import bb.cascades 1.4

Dialog {
    id: activityDialog
    objectName: "activityDialog"
    content: Container {
        id: activityDialogContainer

        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center

        // fully transparent background!
        background: Color.create(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout: StackLayout {

        }
        ActivityIndicator {
           id: theIndicator
           preferredWidth: 500               
           preferredHeight: 500           
        } 
        Label {
            id: activityLabel;
            objectName: "activityLabel";
            text: ""
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        }                   
    }

    onOpened: {
        theIndicator.start();
    }

    onClosed: {
        theIndicator.stop();
    }
}
```

I can then simply open the dialog when I want to display the indicator.

The problem is that the dialog then prevents any interaction with the underlying `Page`'s / `NavigationPane`'s controls. I understand why. The dialog takes up the whole screen and although transparent still essentially hides any UI of the underlying pane.

How can I overlay an `ActivityIndicator` in the centre of the screen without preventing interaction with the underlying panel's controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now realised I simply need to create a `DockLayout` around my main `Container` and the `ActivityIndicator`.